# Mat Checkbox Not change when 'Y'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using angular material . I using mat-checkbox. I got problem,  When I got data 'N' from backed and when I click checked it, it change to 'Y' but from 'Y' to 'N' not change. This [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-checkbox-umsb9s) for your reference.

**HTML**

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="blocked = $event?'Y':'N'" color='primary' [ngModel]="blocked === 'Y'" > IS Blocked?</mat-checkbox>


<br><br>
checkbox is {{blocked}}
```

**Component**

```
blocked:any='N';
```

Comment: How about using the appropriate type for the model of your checkbox, boolean, instead of 'Y' and 'N'? It would make everything much simpler and cleaner: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-checkbox-ny7jpm?file=app%2Fcheckbox-overview-example.ts

Comment: I got data from backend in 'Y' and 'N'

Comment: Then change it in the service or in the component to the correct type, once and for all, so that your code becomes sane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may simply do

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="onChange($event)" color='primary' [ngModel]="blocked == 'Y' ? true : false" > IS Blocked?</mat-checkbox>
```

And in **checkbox-overview-example.ts** put below function.

```
onChange(event){
   this.blocked = event.checked ? 'Y' : 'N';
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: but why when I submit it still pass false when I uncheck?

Comment: It seems because of we assign the value true false in ngModel in ngModel. Pleser refer this line on html [ngModel]="blocked == 'Y' ? true : false"

Comment: A checkbox is a read-only true false value on their checked unchecked event. So you can replace the value on submitting just put the condition if this.blocked == false then you need to replace it by 'N'.

Answer (score 2):

You may simply do:

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="blocked = !blocked" color='primary'> IS Blocked?</mat-checkbox>

checkbox is {{blocked ? 'N' : 'Y'}}
```

Comment: The problem is when I want to send to backend.. It become false.. Not 'N'

Comment: @Pravu Then change it again before sending it to the backend: `const toSendToBackend = blocked ? 'Y' : 'N'`;

Comment: how about `(change)="blocked = !blocked"` change to `(change)='onChange($event)'`

Comment: anything changing `onChange()` function

Answer (score 1):

if you use (change) you sould use $event.checked, see [the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api#MatCheckboxChange)

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="blocked = $event.checked?'Y':'N'" 
              [checked]="blocked === 'Y'" > IS Blocked?</mat-checkbox>
```

if you use (ngModelChange) you use $event

```
<mat-checkbox (ngModelChange)="blocked = $event?'Y':'N'" 
               [ngModel]="blocked === 'Y'" > IS Blocked?</mat-checkbox>
```

NOTE: I like use the pairs (ngModelChange)/[ngModel] or the pair (change)/[checked]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="blocked = $event?'Y':'N'" color='primary' [ngModel]="blocked === 'Y'" > IS Blocked?</mat-checkbox>
```

use:

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="blocked = $event.checked?'Y':'N'" color='primary' [ngModel]="blocked === 'Y'" > IS Blocked?</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: please explain your answer!